# Grouping n or more observations in data table without interrputing sequences of consecutive values

Tags: r, data.table

In R, I have the following sample data table:

```
library(data.table)
type <- c("d1", "d1", "d2", "d3", "d3", "d3", "d4", "d4", "d4", "d4", "d4", "d5", "d5", "d6", "d6")
DT <- data.table(type)
DT[, id := seq(.N), by = .(type)]
```

Which looks like this:

```
# Input:
#
    type id
 1:   d1  1
 2:   d1  2
 3:   d2  1
 4:   d3  1
 5:   d3  2
 6:   d3  3
 7:   d4  1
 8:   d4  2
 9:   d4  3
10:   d4  4
11:   d4  5
12:   d5  1
13:   d5  2
14:   d6  1
15:   d6  2
```

I would like to group observations from the `type` column into chunks of five by adding a new column that contains a unique ID for each group of five. However, sequences of identical values in the `type` column are **not** to be assigned to different group IDs, which means that a chunk may contain more than five elements. In other words, what I try to achieve is to add a column `chunk` with a counter that increases by +1 once five elements have been counted **and** the last sequence of consecutive identical values from the `type` column is completed. The desired output is hence:

```
# Desired output
    type id chunk
 1:   d1  1     1
 2:   d1  2     1
 3:   d2  1     1
 4:   d3  1     1
 5:   d3  2     1
 6:   d3  3     1
 7:   d4  1     2
 8:   d4  2     2
 9:   d4  3     2
10:   d4  4     2
11:   d4  5     2
12:   d5  1     3
13:   d5  2     3
14:   d6  1     3
15:   d6  2     3
```

Any suggestions and help are welcome, especially vectorised solutions. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Fyi `DT[, id := seq(.N), by = .(type)]` can be `DT[, id := rowid(type)]`

Comment: Thank you very much, it's always good to learn different ways of achieving the same outcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DT[, grp := .GRP, type]


i <- 1
DT[1:5, chunk := i] # set chunk = i for first five rows
DT[grp == last(grp[!is.na(chunk)]), chunk := i] # make chunk = i for any rows with same type

while((last.I <- DT[, last(.I[!is.na(chunk)])]) < nrow(DT)){
  i <- i + 1
  DT[last.I + seq(min(c(5, nrow(DT) - last.I))), chunk := i] # set chunk = i for next five rows
  DT[grp == last(grp[!is.na(chunk)]), chunk := i] # make chunk = i for any rows with same type
}
DT[, grp := NULL][]

#     type id chunk
#  1:   d1  1     1
#  2:   d1  2     1
#  3:   d2  1     1
#  4:   d3  1     1
#  5:   d3  2     1
#  6:   d3  3     1
#  7:   d4  1     2
#  8:   d4  2     2
#  9:   d4  3     2
# 10:   d4  4     2
# 11:   d4  5     2
# 12:   d5  1     3
# 13:   d5  2     3
# 14:   d6  1     3
# 15:   d6  2     3
```

@Frank posted a simpler solution in the comments

```
gDT = DT[, .N, by=type][, g := 1L]
s = first(gDT$N)
gg = 1L
for (ii in 1:nrow(gDT)){
  if (s >= 5){ 
    s = 0 
    gg = gg + 1L
    gDT[ii:.N, g := gg][]
  } 
  else s = s + gDT$N[ii]
}
DT[gDT, on=.(type), g := i.g]
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ryan, the above solution using a while loop has solved my problem. On my actual data table of approx. 26M rows and 15 columns (many of which contain text strings) your suggested method took around 10 minutes on a 16GB quad-core laptop, which is perfectly fine for my purposes. However, the second solution using the helper data table (gDT) did not produce the desired output, because the first group contains only 3 elements rather than five or more. In my scenario, only the last chunk may be <= 5. Nevertheless, the first solution is very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Adding a `Rcpp` method and some timings:

sample data:

```
library(Rcpp)
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(0L)
ntypes <- 1e4L
x <- unlist(mapply(rep, 1:ntypes, sample(1:10, ntypes, replace=TRUE)))
DT <- data.table(type=x)
DT1 <- copy(DT)
```

functions defn:

```
system.time(cppFunction(
    'NumericVector lumpGrp(NumericVector x) {
        int counter = 1, grp = 1;
        NumericVector ret(x.size());
        ret[0] = grp;
        for (int n = 1; n < x.size(); n++) {
            if (counter >= 5 && x[n] != x[n-1]) {
                counter = 1;
                grp += 1;
            } else {
                counter += 1;
            }
            ret[n] = grp;
        }
        return ret;
    }'))


mtd0 <- function() {
    gDT = DT1[, .N, by=type][, g := 1L]
    s = first(gDT$N)
    gg = 1L
    for (ii in 1:nrow(gDT)){
        if (s >= 5){
            s = 0
            gg = gg + 1L
            gDT[ii:.N, g := gg][]
        }
        else s = s + gDT$N[ii]
    }
    DT1[gDT, on=.(type), g := i.g]
    DT1
}

mtd1 <- function() {
    DT[, grp := .GRP, type][]

    i <- 1
    DT[1:5, chunk := i] # set chunk = i for first five rows
    DT[grp == last(grp[!is.na(chunk)]), chunk := i] # make chunk = i for any rows with same type

    while((last.I <- DT[, last(.I[!is.na(chunk)])]) < nrow(DT)){
        i <- i + 1
        DT[last.I + seq(min(c(5, nrow(DT) - last.I))), chunk := i] # set chunk = i for next five rows
        DT[grp == last(grp[!is.na(chunk)]), chunk := i] # make chunk = i for any rows with same type
    }
    DT[, grp := NULL][]
}
```

checks:

```
#identical(mtd0()$g, mtd1()$chunk)
#identical(mtd0()$g, lumpGrp(x))

head(x, 50)
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7
#[42] 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 8 8



head(mtd0()$g, 50)
# [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
#[42] 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5

head(mtd1()$chunk, 50)
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
#[42] 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6

head(lumpGrp(x), 50)
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
#[42] 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6



tail(mtd1()$chunk, 20)
#[1] 6807 6807 6807 6808 6808 6808 6808 6808 6809 6809 6809 6809 6809 6809    1    1    1    1    1    1

tail(lumpGrp(x), 20)
#[1] 6807 6807 6807 6808 6808 6808 6808 6808 6809 6809 6809 6809 6809 6809 6810 6810 6810 6810 6810 6810
```

timing code:

```
mtd0 <- compiler::cmpfun(mtd0)
mtd1 <- compiler::cmpfun(mtd1)
microbenchmark(mtd0(), mtd1(), lumpGrp(x), times=3L)
```

timings:

```
Unit: microseconds
       expr         min           lq         mean      median          uq         max neval
     mtd0() 2930021.679 2952683.7490 2972758.5293 2975345.819 2994126.954 3012908.090     3
     mtd1()    7306.673    7573.0050    7763.6367    7839.337    7992.119    8144.900     3
 lumpGrp(x)     431.032     431.3635     476.6073     431.695     499.395     567.095     3
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be

```
DT[, chunk := cumsum(shift(!cumsum(id != shift(id, fill = id[2])) %% 5,
                    fill = TRUE))]
DT
#    type id chunk
# 1:   d1  1     1
# 2:   d1  2     1
# 3:   d2  1     1
# 4:   d3  1     1
# 5:   d3  2     1
# 6:   d3  3     1
# 7:   d4  1     2
# 8:   d4  2     2
# 9:   d4  3     2
#10:   d4  4     2
#11:   d4  5     2
#12:   d5  1     3
#13:   d5  2     3
#14:   d6  1     3
#15:   d6  2     3
```

Comment: Great answer for example data. It won't work if there are > 5 rows with the same `type` though.

Comment: A very elegant suggestion, thank you. However, as stated by Ryan, it does not produce the desired output if there are > 5 rows, which is frequently the case in my real data.